# Apache Camel proxy large file from rest endpoint to rest

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-camel

I have a Spring Boot with Apache Camel application that exposes several rest endpoints and acting as a proxy forward requests to another application. This is the main code:

```
        rest("/multipart")
            .tag("multipart")

            .post("")
            // swagger
            .id("multipartUpload")
            .consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
            .produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .description("Upload large file")
            .type(SaveDocumentDTORequest.class)
            .responseMessage().responseModel(MultipartDocumentDTOResponse.class).code(HttpStatus.OK.value()).endResponseMessage()
            .responseMessage().message(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.getReasonPhrase()).code(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value()).endResponseMessage()
            // route
            .to(documentEndpoint + MultipartService.MULTIPART_PATH + Util.BRIDGE_ENDPOINT + Util.THROW_EXCEPTION_OFF)
```

I'd like to stream the large file (size > 1GB) from Camel to the external application without loading him in memory or caching on a file (streaming cache).

I noticed that org.apache.camel.converter.stream.StreamCacheConverter automatically get the input-stream and full copy in memory using this converter:

```
@Converter(
    order = 2
)
public static StreamCache convertToStreamCache(InputStream stream, Exchange exchange) throws IOException {
    CachedOutputStream cos = new CachedOutputStream(exchange);
    IOHelper.copyAndCloseInput(stream, cos);
    return cos.newStreamCache();
}
```

is there any way to disable it or proxy the file without full loading it somewhere?

Camel version 3.18.0

Thanks.

Comment: Try with disabling (or tuning threshold of) streamcaching  - See https://camel.apache.org/manual/stream-caching.html

Comment: Hi @TacheDeChoco thanks for reply. I already tried the stream-caching...it give me 2 options:
1) it cache the file on file system: too slow for me goals
2) it put the file in memory but this can cause Out Of Memory exception.
I'd like have a simple InputStream to forward to the other application but the default converter (StreamCache convertToStreamCache()) enter in action and I don't know how to override it.